# Full Text Search primer?

Tags: database, indexing, full-text-search

Can anybody recommend a good book(s)/paper(s)/article(s) on Full Text Search (and maybe indexing in general).  I'm pretty anal about having to understand what's happening behind the scenes in my applications, and I'm having trouble understanding why Sphinx and other external FTS's leaves MySQL/MyISAM in the dust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For understanding full text search from the bottom up, I recommend "Managing Gigabytes".

http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/mg/

Answer (score 3):

I found the postgres Full Text Search page http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html very enlightening.

Especially: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-intro.html

Textual search operators have existed in databases for years. PostgreSQL has ~, ~*, LIKE, and ILIKE operators for textual data types, but they lack many essential properties required by modern information systems:

- There is no linguistic support, even
  for English. Regular expressions are
  not sufficient because they cannot
  easily handle derived words, e.g.,
  satisfies and satisfy. You might miss
  documents that contain satisfies,
  although you probably would like to
  find them when searching for satisfy.
  It is possible to use OR to search
  for multiple derived forms, but this
  is tedious and error-prone (some
  words can have several thousand
  derivatives).
- They provide no ordering (ranking) of
  search results, which makes them
  ineffective when thousands of
  matching documents are found.
- They tend to be slow because there is
  no index support, so they must
  process all documents for every
  search.

Answer (score 3):

There is an excellent free Information Retrieval book (Christopher D. Manning, Prabhakar Raghavan and Hinrich Schütze, Introduction to Information Retrieval, Cambridge University Press. 2008), including text search, available free [(legit) here](http://www-csli.stanford.edu/~hinrich/information-retrieval-book.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would start with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). It's for SQL Server, but a reading won't hurt, since many concepts other than implementation details will be (very likely) same across DB's.

Answer (score 0):

“An Object-Oriented Architecture for Text Retrieval”

http://lucene.sourceforge.net/papers/riao91.ps